# XCTest fails to compare two strings

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, xctest, xcuitest

I am looking for a text given in parameter in my textviews. I am sure that it exists because I see it on the screen, but somehow comparing them fails.

Here is a method:

```
func checkText(_ text: String) {
        for tv in app.textViews.allElementsBoundByIndex {
            if let typedText = tv.value as? String {
                print(typedText)
                print(text)
                print(typedText == text)
            }
        }
    }
```

**CONSOLE OUPUT:**

```
This is a test.￼
This is a test.
false
```

I dont know how this is possible.

I have also tried this way:

```
if myTextView.exists {
    if let typedText = myTextView.value as? String {
        XCTAssertEqual(typedText, text, "The texts are not matching")
    }
}
```

But it gives an error saying that the texts are not matching, because "This is a test." is not equal to "This is a test."

Comment: What happens if you compare Array(typedText.utf8) and Array(text.utf8)

Comment: same, it fails @Shadowrun

Comment: What are the values of those - the difference between them will show what is different.  Unicode has lots of ways of having strings that appear visually the same but aren't.

Comment: You are trying to typecast a `Bool` (exists) to a String, typo?

Comment: JoakimDanielson no, I have already pasted what XCTAssertEqual gives me - it says that the two same strings are not the same.

@Shadowrun right, there is a difference at the end of the arrays: XCTAssertEqual failed: ("[84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 46]") is not equal to ("[84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 32, 116, 101, 115, 116, 46, 239, 191, 188]")

Comment: So it's working fine, and it detected that one string has a rogue "U+FFFC" (239, 191, 188 in decimal utf-8) on the end which is the unicode character that is called "Object Replacement Character"

Comment: @stackich Are you typing the text into the text view, or pasting it in from somewhere?

Comment: @ItaiFerber I am typing it using app.typeText()

Comment: `if let typedText = myTextView.exists as? String`

Comment: it was a typo, sorry :)

Comment: @stackich And does your app insert anything else into the text view after/during typing? e.g. images, attachments, etc.? `U+FFFC` is the Unicode `OBJECT REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`, which is a placeholder that indicates a non-text object in a text stream. If your app does no such thing, then I'd consider trying to replicate this scenario in a standalone app, i.e., figure out whether it's somehow your typing that inserts the character in there; and if it doesn't happen in a separate app, it might help you narrow down what's unique to your app that's causing this.

Comment: Looks like it inserts a little "cursor space" at the end of textview when typing finishes. I need to trim it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As guys wrote in the comments, my textview was adding "Object Replacement Character" or "U+FFFC" after it finished editing.

To make the strings equal, I needed to do this:

```
let trimmedTypedText = typedText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{fffc}", with: "")
```

So this will now succeed:

```
if let typedText = myTextView.value as? String {
    let trimmedTypedText = typedText.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{fffc}", with: "")
    XCTAssertEqual(trimmedTypedText, text, "The texts are not matching")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I convert your last 3 bytes which is `[239, 191, 188]`, With using

```
    let array: [UInt8] = [239, 191, 188]
    if let output = String(bytes: array, encoding: .utf8) {
        print("-" + output + "-")
    }
```

The output is :

```
-￼-
```

That means indicates that the last character of one of these strings represents an extra space character

Maybe you are adding to unwanted space to text or in your `XCUIElement` value adds it . Thats why equalization operation returns false

Answer (score 0):

your function seems to work correctly, the "." are not the same between the two texts (check on https://www.diffchecker.com/diff )

Comment: hmmm, how is this possible?

Comment: This isn't exactly correct — the period in both pieces of text is the same character; the first string has an additional invisible character _after_ the period that makes the strings not equal.

Comment: you are right @ItaiFerber. Looks like the code adds a cursor space at the end of the textview's text , which is invisible.